# How to fix a scroll to anchor single page responsive menu?

Tags: jquery, css

I created a single page design. Where all the content is on one place - the homepage. With jQuery I code to create a go to anchor navigation. When scrolling the current state of the menu is updating and when click on a link, it will scroll to the right position/section of that link.

Unfortunately, the menu isn't working great on tablet and smartphone.
When I change the viewport to tablet, it will scroll to the position, but then it will stop to early, so it's not on the top of the browser. On mobile it will scroll to the wrong position and `organisatie` will be always the current menu item.Is there a fix for this issue?

```
// One Page Navigation - scroll to anchor id
    $('#primary-navwrapper, #footer .list-of-links').find('li a[href^="#"]').click(function(event) { 
    //primary-navwrapper li:not(.prev-page, .next-page), .list-of-links li

        // Prevent from default action to intitiate
        event.preventDefault();

        // Update active class on click
        $('#primary-navwrapper li a').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        // The id of the section we want to go to
        // var anchor = this.hash;
        var anchorId = $(this).attr('href');
        //console.log(anchorId);
        scrollToAnchor(anchorId);

        if (isMobile) {
            nav.slideToggle();
        } 

        return false;

    });


    function scrollToAnchor(anchorId) {

        // Our scroll target : the top position of the section that has the id referenced by our href
        if (anchorId.length) {
            var target = $(anchorId).offset().top - offset;
            //console.log("target" + target);
        }


        // The magic...smooth scrollin' goodness.
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: target }, 500, function () {
            //window.location.hash = '!' + id;
            window.location.hash = anchorId;        
        });

    }
```

You can see it live [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pJLwbR?editors=101).

Comment: You have deleted your last question? Why ? I have done with ans